# Add the "focus on active task" filter

Tags: eclipse, task, aptana, mylyn

I just installed Aptana, and I really like it. However, I am wondering where my Mylyn filters are, as I cannot get the *focus on active task* button in Aptana file view or in the navigator. How can this be fixed?

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mylyn only natively supports a certain set of stock Eclipse views, and the views you mention aren't included in that list. In order to add that support, a connector has to be created for Aptana Studio 2.

As a note, in Studio 3, Mylyn works against the Project Explorer already. There is a ticket to add support for the App Explorer.

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/2209-add-mylyn-task-filter-to-app-explorer

HTH,
Ingo